# how to retry execute piece of code if certain data count is zero

Tags: c#

I have a list of string which fills every one minute by with an API call,

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
```

Now I need to retry code within method `PerformSomeAction` after 1 minute, if my `lst` count is zero, how to do this?

Can I use `Polly`?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();

        if(lst.Count > 0)
        {
            //retry after one minute of lst.Count == 0
            PerformSomeAction();
        }
    }

    private static void PerformSomeAction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("execute");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy to achieve:

```
while(lst.Count == 0)
{
  Thread.Sleep(1000*60);
  PerformAction();
}
```

Comment: @JoseAntonioNavarroMarco Who said that I cannot? It's not about multithreading, just simple solution. What other actions ar there to execute? What would be benefit from not freezing the thread?

Comment: Well, I think he simplified the code, you don't know how the real code looks like.

Comment: @JoseAntonioNavarroMarco He didn't mention nothing about asynchronous calls, so your remark is valid, but not relevant here.

Comment: He mentions he's working with an API, I'm almost certain some asynchronous calls are made.